# Making comparison between people (verb)

Tags: translation, verbs

I'm wondering how to construct sentences like: I am better than genji san at cooking. In other words, comparison between what people can do.

I'm aware of the noun1 yori noun2 nohouga property desu construction, though that can't be used for people.

Comment: Why can't?
私の方がゲンジより料理が上手いです。
Are you told this construction is bad?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, より [can be used with people](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A).

> 「彼女{かのじょ}はトムより年上{としうえ}だ」 (kanojo ha tomu yori toshiue da)

She is older than Tom. より marks the thing or person being compared.

You don't necessarily have to include the のほうが. You can find other comparisons between people in that link.

Also, see the JLPT5 grammar flash card for [方 より](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-flashcard-17/).

Sentence 2 on the card reads:

> 学生{がくせい}より先生{せんせい}の方{ほう}がこの問題{もんだい}を理解{りかい}できる。(gakusei yori sensei no hou ga kono mondai wo rikai dekiru)

Teachers can understand this problem better than students.

This is a comparison between people using both 方 and より

Comment: Sorry; I don't know if you're comfortable with kana and kanji or not, but より is yori and 方/ほう is hou. I wasn't sure because you used romaji in your question (maybe because you didn't have a Japanese IME).

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, your sentence should be like this: 
私はゲンジさんより料理が上手です。With the の方が construction it's mostly used when you want to talk about your preferences, such as 私は犬より猫の方が好きです。
Hope it helps!